# In Groovy, what's the difference between assigning to an empty list vs creating a new ArrayList<T>?

Tags: java, memory-management, groovy

I'm initializing an empty list of objects:

```
List<T> firstEmptyList = []
```

What's the difference between doing that, and something like this:

```
List<T> secondEmptyList = new ArrayList<T>()
```

Does the latter take up more space/memory? Do they behave differently?

Comment: Nothing... They're the same